# Dual boot setup, cannot get into ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a laptop with a 256gb pcie ssd for windows and i added in a 2tb hard drive for linux and windows storage.  I booted from my ubuntu 16.04 usb stick but when i went to install it, he installation menu said that no other operating system was detected on my computer.  So i manually created a 1tb partition on my hdd and installed ubuntu there, but now i cannot boot into linux.  In windows, the disk management tool marks that partition as "active" so it should be bootable but it is nowhere in my bios as an option.  When i power up my laptop, it goes straight into windows.  How do I get into my ubuntu install? I assume this is more of a problem with my bios than anything

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? And did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode on second drive? Best to see your details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Some info on gpt partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Windows is UEFI. I installed Linux as legacy the first time but I tried to install as UEFI and it won't detect my Windows install. The Linux partition is on second drive. If I manually install Linux as UEFI will grub be able to detect windows and dual boot properly?

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Or once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. So grub can only offer to boot other systems installed in same boot mode as grub/Ubuntu is installed in. From UEFI boot menu you can dual boot as you are starting system in that mode. Link in first answer above is about gpt partitioning for UEFI install, us that on second drive and boot installer in UEFI mode and use Something Else to install.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me...very frustrating.
What I did was going into BIOS, disabling Secure boot and then enabling Legacy boot/mode.

Then when I start up my PC, it says pres ESC for boot menu or something like that. I press it, then choose I can choose ubuntu / windows. Then after I choose ubuntu it goes into the GRUB menu, I choose ubuntu one more time and then ubuntu boots.

This worked for me, it might work for you and it might not. Give it a try.
Hope it helps.